# How to add degree symbol to multiple plot legend entries in R?

Tags: r, string, plot, expression, legend

I know I can add a degree symbol to a plot legend by using `expression`.

```
plot(1:5,1:5)
legend('topleft', fill = 'white', legend = expression(5~degree~C))
```

[image]

But **How can I do this for *multiple* legend entries?**

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
plot(1:5,1:5)
points(1:5,(1:5) + 0.1, col = 2)
legend('topleft', fill = c('white','red'), legend = paste0(c(5,10), expression(~degree~C)))
```

[image]

**Edit:** I am more interested in how to do this for *many* values, not just 2.

Any suggestions on how to do this succinctly and neatly would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the help of `substitute` and `expression`. You do a sapply of the vector for which you need to write the expression, here i am putting `c(5,10)` as input of sapply. For the function part, you need to use as.expression with substitute.

```
plot(1:5,1:5)
points(1:5,(1:5) + 0.1, col = 2)
legend('topleft', fill = c('white','red'), legend = sapply(c(5,10), function(x) as.expression(substitute(A~degree~"C",list(A = as.name(x))))))
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For ggplot:

```
ylab(expression(paste("SST (",degree~C,")"))) +
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include both values in the expression

```
  legend('topleft', fill = c('white','red'), expression(5~degree~C,10~degree~C))
```

Comment: Oy, duhh! Thanks! However, is there a way to do this quickly with, say, 20 different values? (I.e. instead of repeating the expression 20x, is there a way to just write the `~degree~C` once and have it combine with each of 20 values)?